# Can one have a mixed makefile with .c and and .cu files? if so, how?

Tags: c, makefile, cuda

I currently have a makefile that is coded to compile OpenACC and I was wondering if I can make it support .cu as well

My current makefle:

```
LDFLAGS += -Ldcmt0.4/lib -ldcmt
include Makefile.include


HW1_INCS = black_scholes.h gaussian.h parser.h random.h timer.h util.h
HW1_C_SRCS = black_scholes.c gaussian.c main.c parser.c random.c dcmt0.4/lib/random_seed.c timer.c util.c
HW1_C_OBJS = $(HW1_C_SRCS:.c=.o)
HW1_EXE = hw1.x

all: hw1.x

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $(ACCFLAGS) $< -o $@

hw1.x: $(HW1_C_OBJS) dcmt0.4/lib/libdcmt.a
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(HW1_C_OBJS) -o $@

dcmt0.4/lib/libdcmt.a: 
    make -C dcmt0.4/lib
black_scholes.o: black_scholes.c black_scholes.h gaussian.h random.h util.h
gaussian.o: gaussian.c gaussian.h util.h
main.o: main.c black_scholes.h parser.h random.h timer.h
parser.o: parser.c parser.h
random.o: random.c random.h
dcmt0.4/lib/random_seed.o: dcmt0.4/lib/random_seed.c
timer.o: timer.c timer.h
util.o: util.c util.h

clean:
    make -C dcmt0.4/lib clean
    rm -f $(HW1_C_OBJS) $(HW1_EXE)
```

Makefile.include:

```
CC = nvc
LINKER = nvc
LDFLAGS = -lm
```

I am planning to include Cuda in black_scholes.c so it will become black_scholes.cu while leaving other things as they are. However, I am not sure if I can do this in a single makefile and I am pretty novice when it comes to them.

For example, having `HW1_C_SRCS` and `HW1_C_OBJS` contain `.c` extensions, but I have to change black_scholes to become .c

Similarly, the compiler flags will chance, any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: "I am planning to include Cuda in black_scholes.c " -- you can't do that. nvcc uses file extension to determine compilation path, if you keep a .c extension it will hand off to the host compiler  and fail to compiler. Note also that CUDA code is compiled with C++ linkage, so you will have to either deal with mangled symbols or modify the CUDA code to specify C linkage for everything you call from the C code

Comment: I would change it to black_scholes.cu, sorry I made a typo in the answer, but I do not know how to modify the makefile accordingly

Comment: @Sergio does the solution I provided works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below code by which you can use in the same makefile which will compile all files (.c and .cu) .

```
LDFLAGS += -Ldcmt0.4/lib -ldcmt
include Makefile.include


HW1_INCS = black_scholes.h gaussian.h parser.h random.h timer.h util.h
# Add your .c files here
HW1_C_SRCS = gaussian.c main.c parser.c random.c
# Add your .cu files here
HW1_CUDA_SRCS = black_scholes.cu
HW1_C_OBJS = $(HW1_C_SRCS:.c=.o)
HW1_CUDA_OBJS = $(HW1_CUDA_SRCS:.cu=.o)
HW1_EXE = hw1.x

all: hw1.x

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $(ACCFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.o: %.cu
    # Here you can also put a variable CUDAFLAGS instead of CCFLAGS if you want to pass
    # different compiler flags to .cu file. You can define the variable CUDAFLAGS in makefile.include
    $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $(ACCFLAGS) $< -o $@

hw1.x: $(HW1_C_OBJS) $(HW1_CUDA_OBJS) dcmt0.4/lib/libdcmt.a
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(HW1_C_OBJS) $(HW1_CUDA_OBJS) -o $@

dcmt0.4/lib/libdcmt.a: 
    make -C dcmt0.4/lib

black_scholes.o: black_scholes.cu black_scholes.h gaussian.h random.h util.h
gaussian.o: gaussian.c gaussian.h util.h
main.o: main.c black_scholes.h parser.h random.h timer.h
parser.o: parser.c parser.h
random.o: random.c random.h
dcmt0.4/lib/random_seed.o: dcmt0.4/lib/random_seed.c
timer.o: timer.c timer.h
util.o: util.c util.h

clean:
    make -C dcmt0.4/lib clean
    rm -f $(HW1_C_OBJS) $(HW1_CUDA_OBJS) $(HW1_EXE)
```

Please note: This is just an example to get you started.
Run :
**make all**

Comment: I got the following using both commands: "make: *** No rule to make target 'black_scholes.c', needed by 'black_scholes.o'.  Stop."

Comment: @sergio : It means black_scholes.c file is not available to make.Check if the file exists. I gave you a reference example on how you can use a switch and just toggle conditions based on it . By this way you can achieve your functionality of using same makefile.

Comment: it doesn't exist since I put cuda code in it and switched it to .cu, shall I ever the extension?

Comment: Sorry ,now i am bit confused. So you create a file with .cu extension and save it , and then you want this .cu file to compile ?

Comment: yes, I have black_scholes.cu  and gaussian.c main.c parser.c random.c and I want all to compile

Comment: the makefile I put is for when all files were .c

Comment: I think then good option for you would be to create separate makefile (cuda.mak) and default.mak which will contain necessary flags releated to cuda and the defualt ones. You can include one of the files based on the switch. Example in your main makefile:  ```ifeq "$(COMPILER_CUDA)" "true"
   # include cuda.mak file
   include cuda.mak
else
 # Default compiler 
 include default.mak
endif```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232352/discussion-between-altaf-and-sergio).